# php - bcadd has different point precision

Tags: php, floating-point-precision, bcmath

On my windows box when I run

```
  $SR = "0";
  $SPR = "149";
  $SR = bcadd($SR, $SPR);
  echo "$SR";
```

It outputs `149.0000000000`

But when I upload the same code to my Linux host, the output is `149`.

Why?

Comment: PHP floating point precision depends on Operation System, as said in PHP manual

Answer (score 3, accepted):

probably the "scale" is different on the two environments.

Try to set the scale with the [bcscale](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcscale.php) function before doing your operations, For example:

```
bcscale(3);

$SR = "0";
$SPR = "149";
$SR = bcadd($SR, $SPR);
echo "$SR";
```

Or simply use the third parameter in [bcadd](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcadd.php) to set the scale:

```
$SR = "0";
$SPR = "149";
$SR = bcadd($SR, $SPR, 3);
echo "$SR";
```

Comment: Yes, needed a `bcscale(0);`, Thanks!